# Why Axios doesn't manage to use my url params in prod mode?

Tags: axios, sequelize.js

I'm having trouble getting my axios `.get` in production with React because in dev mode everything work perfectly.

In dev mode, I have a url *(https://www.mon-gouvernement.fr/gouvernement/1)* that at the end a number. This number is use to get my data from my database. But in production, I got error in my terminal.

[image]

**server.js** with sequelize module to manage my database

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const db = require('./models');

//************************************************
// ROUTES
//************************************************
const governmentCreateRouter = require('./routes/GovernmentCreate');
app.use("/governmentCreate", governmentCreateRouter);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});


db.sequelize.sync().then(() => {
    app.listen();
});
```

**GovernmentCreate.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { GovernmentCreate } = require('../models');

router.get("/byId/:id", async (req, res) => {
 const id =req.params.id;
 const GovernmentId = await GovernmentCreate.findByPk(id, {
    include: {all: true}
});
 res.json(GovernmentId);
});
```

Part of code inside my **GouvernmentId.js** that is called with url `https://www.mon-gouvernement.fr/gouvernement/1`.

```
let { id } = useParams();
console.log(id)

axios.get(`https://www.mon-gouvernement.fr/governmentCreate/byId/${id}`)
            .then((res) => {

                console.log(res.data)

                setGovernmentList([res.data]);

            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
```

**app.js**

```
<BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/a-propos" element={<About />} />
            <Route path="/creer-son-gouvernement" element={<CreateGovernment />} />
            <Route path="/gouvernement-galerie" element={<GovernmentWall />} />
            <Route path="/gouvernement/:id" element={<GovernmentId />} />
            <Route path="*" element={<Error404 />} />
          </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

**Error** I got

[image]

```
La feuille de style https://www.mon-gouvernement.fr/gouvernement/static/css/main.3eea6a9b.css n’a pas été chargée car son type MIME, « text/html », n’est pas « text/css ».
Le script à l’adresse « https://www.mon-gouvernement.fr/gouvernement/static/js/main.02a475ac.js » a été chargé alors que son type MIME (« text/html ») n’est pas un type MIME JavaScript valide.
Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
```

I understand that my URL (https://www.mon-gouvernement.fr/gouvernement/:id) is caught by `.get('/*'` on my server.js. But why it don't return page ? On my others pages everything work perfectly.

Comment: Look at the _response_ you're actually getting, I'll bet it's `index.html` again. It would be much easier if you moved your API routes under a common root (like `/api`, as I've done in https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit).

Comment: Ok, I get. It's again the same problem but I don't find my answer in your exemple. In dev mode everything work well. So, why in prod the routes doesn't work ? Normaly when `express` detect `/governmentCreate` inside the url it use route to search my `GovernementCreate.js`. In this file, it will find information to treate the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solve my issu** with the code below. I add into my **package.json** this line

```
"homepage": "https://www.mon-gouvernement.fr/",
```